# Rails convert datetime to date inwhere()

Tags: date, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I've got the following problem:

i need to convert a datetime field in a where select to a date field.

```
scope :after_start_date, lambda { |value| where('end_time <= (?)', value) if value}
```

I need something like where(end_time.to_date + " >= (?)", value)

Is there a nice way to do this?

Update/Example

- 08.09.2014 14:40 as DB_END_TIME
- 08.09.2014 AS PARAM_END_TIME

I wanna get all results which until the date 08.09.2014 (including the 8th), 
but the comparison `where(DB_END_TIME <= PARAM_END_TIME)` does not include 08.09.2014 
because the PARAM_END_TIME has 00:00:00 as time value.

And i think its not nice to do something like this:
`PARAM_END_TIME + 1.day - 1.second` - this would work.

So i'd like to convert the database value to the date format in the where statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ruby [**strftime**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) method to create ur own date/time display.

time.strftime( string ) => string

```
  %a - The abbreviated weekday name (``Sun'')
  %A - The  full  weekday  name (``Sunday'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
  %B - The  full  month  name (``January'')
  %c - The preferred local date and time representation
  %d - Day of the month (01..31)
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
  %j - Day of the year (001..366)
  %m - Month of the year (01..12)
  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
  %p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
  %S - Second of the minute (00..60)
  %U - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Sunday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %W - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Monday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
  %x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time
  %X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date
  %y - Year without a century (00..99)
  %Y - Year with century
  %Z - Time zone name
  %% - Literal ``%'' character

   t = Time.now
   t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 04/09/2003"
   t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:56AM"
```

Example:

```
date = Date.parse('2014-09-08 00:00:00 UTC')
# => Mon, 08 Sep 2014
date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
# => "08-09-2014"
```

And search in database accordingly.. I hope this may helps you

**Edit:**
If you want to fetch data from your SQL Server and convert datetime to date then have a [**look at this**](http://sqlhints.com/2013/07/14/how-to-get-date-part-only-from-datetime-in-sql-server/)

Comment: thx, i updated my problem description. So i hope its more cleary whats the problem.

Comment: @user3726033  : so you mean you want to convert datetime to date of DB stored data??

Comment: @user3726033 : check my edit part in my answer... and if it helps you then you can upvote and accept ;)